# How does Quarkus Kotlin/Java Interoperability work?

Tags: kotlin, interop, quarkus

I have a regular Quarkus Java application and I want to introduce some Kotlin classess via CDI and also the Event Bus but the following isn't working as I thought it would.

Case #1 - Event Bus

Kotlin Class

```
@ApplicationScoped
class GreetingServiceBus {
    @ConsumeEvent("KotlinTest")
    fun greeting(name: String) {
        System.out.println("hello $name");
    }
}
```

I call it from Resteasy class like this but greeting is never called (this works fine for Java Class with @ConsumeEvent("KotlinTest")

```
@Path("/api")
public class ApiExecute {
  @Inject
  EventBus eventBus;

  @POST
  @Path("/execute")
  public Response execute() {
    eventBus.send("KotlinTest", "Hello");
```

Case #2 - CDI

Kotlin Class

```
@ApplicationScoped
class GreetingService {
    fun greeting(name: String): String {
        return "hello $name"
    }
}
```

Resteasy Endpoint

```
@Path("/api")
public class ApiExecute {

  @Inject
  GreetingService greetingService;
```

Error

> error: cannot find symbol   GreetingService greetingService;

I saw something about using this with CDI "@field: Default" but I believe that's only available in Kotlin not Java?

Also tried constructor injection but same issue

```
  @POST
  @Path("/execute")
  @Inject
  public Response execute(GreetingService greetingService, String input) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Both constructor and field injection should work just fine with Kotlin.

Have a look at our [integration test](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/3.6.3/integration-tests/resteasy-reactive-kotlin/standard/src/main/kotlin/io/quarkus/it/resteasy/reactive/kotlin) to see various usages

Comment: Can you please point me to a test case where a Kotlin class is injected into a regular Java class? All those integration tests are written in Kotlin from what I can see. I don't have any issue injecting Kotlin into Kotin.